# Ubuntu 20.4 LTS touchpad acting very wierdly

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, xinput

It’s been almost three hours since I installed ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS on my old laptop (Dell Latittude E5420), and my touchpad is acting very weirdly: it automatically clicks, laggs, completely stop working, sticks and moves wierdly. It still works but not like it worked 3 hours before I restarted my computer, and THEN BOOM problem begins.

I’ve tried troubleshooting it with different things like installing different drivers (eg synaptics etc) but nothing worked.

i faced the same problem in linux mint when i installed it on the same laptop i first thought that it was a linux mint error but that same problem is in ubuntu as well(because mint is based on ubuntu)

OS: ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS
LAPTOP: dell latittude 5420

Almost no additional packages installed but xserver-xorg-input-mouse,edev,synaptics and chrome.

output of
`xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD: I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

sorry if it is kinda messed up
if any other information is required i am willing to give

Comment: What was the point of installing " synaptics edev mouse"?

Comment: i was trying to trouble shoot and from edev mouse and synaptics i mean 
xserver-xorg-input-mouse xserver-xorg-input-edev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB and check how it works there.

Comment: it works perfectly fine at the beginning and in the live env but starts doing problems after the first or second  reboot after installation

Comment: You probably do something wrong after an installation.

Comment: ooops i forgot to mention something i faced the exact same issue with mint on the same laptop and i thought that it could be just an issue with mint as it is completely community-driven but turns out the same problem is in ubuntu,     i also have manjaro installed and it works perfectly fine

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1378025/edit) your question and add the output of `xinput list`.  I have read that sometimes there are multiple TouchPads listed which confuses the actual input device daemon.

Comment: Not sure what that Virtual Core XTEST pointer is, but it might be causing conflicts with the Alps driver.

Comment: but there is also a Virtual Core XTEST keyboard

Comment: then which one should i disable and how ive tried multiple things none of them worked so

Comment: I looked at mine too, the XTEST is there, so don't disable it.  It could also be that Canonical / Dell may not have ever updated the Alps driver beyond Ubuntu 10.10.  https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=c7p1w&oscode=wn104&productcode=latitude-e5420

Comment: so i should replace the driver than ???

Comment: wouldn't it be kinda risky that i am using such an old driver on a newer version of ubuntu

Comment: I really don't know.  You can try other things from Dell.  The issue is the laptop is aging and the support for Linux may be dwindling as well.  This shows to update to the HWE Kernel https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000150104/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix it is showing for 16.04, but you can update 20.04 to HWE as well.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  Just follow the Server Install.